# Why can I not concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects inside a class?

Tags: python, string, class, instance, init

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = text

    def printText(text):
            more_text = "Why so "

            return more_text + text
```

Above is a over-simplified version of a code that I am constructing to extract data out of webpages. I am running the temp.py code like this.

```
>>> from temp import myClass
>>> text = "serious?"
>>> joker_says = myClass(text)
>>>
>>> print joker_says.printText()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "temp.py", line 9, in printText
    return more_text + text
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

I have seen many examples of concatenation issues of 'str' and 'instance' objects in Stack Overflow.

I have tried the following ways:

OPTION 1: CONVERT text TO STRING DURING **init** AS INPUT

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, str(text)):
            self.text = text

    def printText(text):
            more_text = "Why so "

            return more_text + text
```

But I get ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "temp.py", line 3
    def __init__(self, str(text)):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

== == == == == ==

OPTION 2: CONVERT text TO STRING DURING **init** STEP

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = str(text)

    def printText(text):
            more_text = "Why so "

            return more_text + text
```

But I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "temp.py", line 9, in printText
    return more_text + text
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

Can someone please give me a good solution to the problem? Please note that in my original code, my intention is to concatenate two string objects inside the class to create a webpage link. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: since `text` in `printText` is the first argument to your *method*, it is *implicitly passed the instance, thus, it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues here:

On every function you create for an object, `self` must be included as the first parameter.

Using your second example:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = str(text)

    def printText(self, text):
            more_text = "Why so "

            return more_text + text
```

Then, you make an instance of your class, and you can access the function `printText` :

```
joker = myClass("This is some text")
print(joker.text) # This prints: "This is some text"
print(joker.printText("serious?")) # This prints "Why so serious?"
```

If you want to use that same text as the initializing text, you need to reference it, instead of as a new parameter `text`, as an attribute of the class, as so:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = str(text)

    def printText(self):
            more_text = "Why so "

            return more_text + self.text
```

Then, if you want to reference the above:

```
joker = myClass("serious?")
print(joker.text) # This prints: "serious?"
print(joker.printText()) # This prints "Why so serious?"
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. However, I think as you pointed out, there should be a self in def printText, but not text. That way printData doesn't look for two inputs. I appreciate the swift response!

Answer (score 2):

The main problem you are facing is this:

```
def printText(text):
```

The reason why you are getting this error is because, as an instance method, the declaration expects you to have `self` (the instance object) passed as first argument. You are now passing `text` which is being used as *self* (the instance). This is why you get the error, because ultimately what you are actually doing *is* trying to add a string with an instance.

So, knowing that the first argument being passed implicitly to `printText` is the instance, and looking inside your method, you are *actually* wanting to reference the `self.text` inside your `printText` method. However, your *instance* being passed in to `printText` is actually referred to as `text`. This can be very confusing.

So, following the suggested nomenclature, you should be naming your instance argument as the "expected", self.

With this in mind, your `text` that you want to reference, can now be referenced as `self.text`.

This can be shown by fixing your code:

```
def printText(self):
        more_text = "Why so "

        return more_text + self.text
```

Comment: Note, OP is using `print joker_says.printText()` so that will throw a `TypeError` because it will be missing an argument...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Shoot. You just made me realize what the real problem is. Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I fixed it.